# Hompage goes to 404 element in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router

I have made an website using ReactJS. Everything goes well on development server (**npm start**)

I build the final version ready to be uploaded on host **run build**

I try to access one of the pages on **build folder**, but it renders me nothing.

The only page it renders is the **404 page** when I try to enter the home page. Which is wrong.

I have tried to use HashRouter. But the URLs are ugly.

I am using React Router v6.
This is the git https://github.com/AlexBrasoveanu/adstoriav2

Help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this your home screen?

I ran your code on codesand box it produced this.

[image]

Comment: Yes. That should be the home screen. But it doesn't work when I open index.html from build folder. It renders the 404 page and the others pages not working at all.